# How can we have Multicharacter line separator (line delimiter) in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can we have multicharacter line separator (line delimiter) in Spark?

Spark 3 allows multicharacter column delimiter but for line separator it only allows one character.

e.g. how to have this: `@@@\n` as line separator?

Comment: Welcome! Can you specify what you're trying to do? Read a file? What does your data look like? Try making a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and that will make your answer be answered more quickly :)

Comment: Is this for reading or writing? Read has a "sep" option and write should have an escape option.

Comment: @EdwardMendez  This is for Writing. Write has lineSep option which takes only one character.  Can we use escape to mention additional characters for line separator ?           
   DF.coalesce(1).write
      .option("delimiter","|")
      .option("lineSep","\n")
      .csv( Path )